# Web API calling Web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a .net Web API 2 application that I need to use to call an web service (asmx) just to see if the web service is up and running correctly.  I am a believer in architecture, so with that in mind I am not sure where to put the call to the web service.  I found a post that suggested that I put this in the repository layer.  Is this the correct location for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say its more of a personal preference + project specific; IMO you can place that web service in repository if it acts as a data-store or you could place it in business layer of the service does more of a business related stuffs.

But one thing I would do for sure is to create a wrapper/abstraction over this service before using it in any layer so that:

- I can inject this dependency in the layers its being used
- Unit testable code - DI and mockable
- No changes in the layers where this is being consumed in case there is any change in service-  for eg, asmx1 to asmx2 or change in asmx service to wcf or REST etc.

*Not sure whether you will be able to find a specific answer to this, this is kinda arguable subject as opinions might differ according to personal preference*